# coin toss simulator won't count heads and tails

Tags: c#

I am trying to make a coin toss simulator program that will toss a coin a number of times based on what the number the user entered. It will display the coin toss number and heads or tails. It will then display how many heads and tails was flipped but It doesn't display the correct number of times, I am not sure how to fix this

any help would be appreciated

Here is what I got so far

```
Console.Write("\n\n");
Console.Write("------------------------------------------------");
Console.WriteLine("\nThis Program simulates tossing a coin mutliple times");
Console.Write("------------------------------------------------");
Console.Write("\n\n");

int Heads = 0, Tails = 0;
int compChoice = 0;

int attempts;                       
Random rnd = new Random();
Console.WriteLine("How many coin tosses?");
coinTossChoice = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
attempts = coinTossChoice;
compChoice = rnd.Next(0, 2);

do
{


    if (attempts == coinTossChoice)
    {
        if (compChoice == 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Toss Number# ");
            Console.WriteLine("\nHeads");
            Heads++;
        }
        else if (compChoice == 1)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Toss Number# ");
            Console.WriteLine("\nTails");
            Tails++;
        }                                                                 
    }
} while (attempts != coinTossChoice);
Console.WriteLine("\nNumber of Heads {0} Number of Tails {1} .", Heads, Tails);
```

Comment: You never change the value of `compChoice`. You assign one random number to it at the start of the program, but you never call `rnd.Next()` again in the loop. Also, what is the intent of `attempts == coinTossChoice`? You want the body of the loop to run `coinTossChoice` number of times, but then you block off the body so it only executes once, and you also never change the number of attempts.

Comment: You need to start attempts at *zero* because no attempts have been made yet. Then for each attempt, get a new random number and decide if it's heads or tails. After that, on each attempt, add one to `attempts`, to keep track of the number of attempts that have been made. Get rid of that `if` in the loop.

Comment: Also, why duplicate the line `Console.WriteLine("Toss Number# " + attempts);` in each `if/else` block?  Just do that once before the `if` statement, keep your code [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, there were some details in your code, I commented the changes I made so you can understand the idea.

```
        Console.Write("\n\n");
        Console.Write("------------------------------------------------");
        Console.WriteLine("\nThis Program simulates tossing a coin mutliple times");
        Console.Write("------------------------------------------------");
        Console.Write("\n\n");

        int Heads = 0, Tails = 0;
        int compChoice = 0;

        int attempts;
        Random rnd = new Random();
        Console.WriteLine("How many coin tosses?");
        int coinTossChoice = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        //attempts is the counter for each toss
        attempts = 1;


        do
        {
            //compChoice is the coin toss containing 0 or 1 at random
            compChoice = rnd.Next(0, 2);
            if (compChoice == 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Toss Number# " + attempts);
                Console.WriteLine("\nHeads");
                Heads++;
            }
            else if (compChoice == 1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Toss Number# " + attempts);
                Console.WriteLine("\nTails");
                Tails++;
            }
        //increment attempt
        attempts++;
        //cycle as many times as the user requested
        } while (attempts <= coinTossChoice);
        Console.WriteLine("\nNumber of Heads {0} Number of Tails {1} .", Heads, Tails);
        Console.ReadKey();
```